# Mathematica piecewise function bad plot rendering

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, piecewise

I wanted to plot a user-defined Piecewise function (pagoda function) in Mathematica 10.2. 
It seems straightforward to me unfortunately the easy command leads to a bad result.

My first approach was:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{0, x <= -1}, {-Abs[x] + 1, -1 < x < 1}, {0, 
x >= 1}}]

Plot3D[ 5*f[x]*f[y], {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}]
```

I also tried to set MaxRecursion which lead to more terrible results in a few cases (e.g. 2,3).

Can anybody tell me how to plot this function in a smooth nice way?

Thanks,

Felix

[image: Example image from Mathematica 10.2]

Comment: give option `Exclusions -> None` to `Plot3D`  (along with increased plotpoints)

Comment: Using only PlotPoint didn't work. But the Exclusisons -> None solved it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can remember, making *visible gaps* was introduced as a feature. Before that, piecewise or discontinuous functions were plotted like this:

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{x, x <= 1}, {3, x > 1}}], {x, 0, 3}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That behavior gives the wrong impression. I would have to check when this was default or if I'm completely off here. Anyway, as already noted in the comments, you can use the `Exclusions` option to get connected graphs.

You don't need to increase `PlotPoints` because Mathematica will (hopefully always) recognize the boundaries of the pieces as places where it needs to recursively increase points. Therefore, the `MaxRecursion` option is far more important to give a smooth plot. This example was rendered with only 10 points, but a recursion value of 5:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Therefore, your function renders extremely well even with 10 plot-points when the recursion is high enough. Look how many subdivisions you get on the cracks

```
Plot3D[5*f[x]*f[y], {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 6, Mesh -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally, note that the gaps are not restricted to `Piecewise` functions. As you can verify yourself, `UnitStep` will also show gaps. You can try it with your example by using an undocumented function to turn everything to `UnitStep`:

```
Simplify`PWToUnitStep[5*f[x]*f[y]]
(*
 5 (1 - Abs[x]) (1 - Abs[y]) (1 - UnitStep[-1 - x]) (1 - 
   UnitStep[-1 + x]) (1 - UnitStep[-1 - y]) (1 - UnitStep[-1 + y])
*)
```

Answer (score 0):

With all due respect to @halirutan, by itself `MaxRecursion` set to 6 was not enough in the following plot to adjust the peak values of a piecewise function to be a monotonic increasing sequence:
[image]
This improved, when, in addition, I set `PlotPoints` to 240, as follows.
[image]
However, that does not completely solve all the display problems. For example, note in the plots above, that the initial value *y* = 0, is not correctly plotted as a blue vertical line despite use of `Exclusions->None`. Moreover, the grid lines, which are `Dotted`, do not display as dots, but as dashes which run off below the *x*-axis.  All of these problems can be solved, probably more efficiently, by generating the points or dots as list data and using `ListPlot` or, as in this case `ListLogPlot` and using `Joined->True` when appropriate. That is low level solution, but is needed in more complicated plots to obtain a plot with shorter run time and more accessible control over the display features.